# Variable needs to be declared from inner class

Tags: java, android-studio

In android studio I have a problem:

```
variable 'button' is accessed from withing inner class, needs to be declared final.
```

How do I fix this ?

Comment: Is this really a `python` problem?

Comment: @kiran.koduru where do you see anything about python?

Comment: @j.seashell: There was a `python` tag which is later editted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just type **final** before your variable.
For example:

```
final button;
```

This should do the job.

Comment: Bingo! Just what I needed!